# Nginx Clean url

Tags: html, url, nginx, url-rewriting, clean-url

I need clean urls for my website.

Html should be removed from the url name and if a website visitor should be able to visit my website without entering .html.

Can someone help me how to do this with the rewrite feature?

I use the Admin Software Plesk with the nginx Server!

Answer (score 1):

You can read from the official [blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) or you can try something like this.
They must be inside location / {}

```
 http://example.com/page
http://example.com/page.html

rewrite ^/page?$ /page.html last;
```

Comment: Thaaaaaaaanks Габриел Кънев!

It works PERFECT. You are so great.
I read so many tips on the internet, but none worked.
Your tip is short and perfect! Many Thanks!